# Expected an assignment or function call error using the componentdidmount function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a timer component such that it would tick only if a boolean isRunning variable is true. It's kind of similiar to the react basic tutorial:
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

But for some reason my didmount function returns an error " Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression".

If can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong it would be great.

Here is my code:

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';

class Timer extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count : 0
        }
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        {
            {this.props.isRunning ? this.myInterval = setInterval(() => 
                { this.tick()}, 1000) : null}
        }
    }

    tick() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        })

    }

    
    render () {
        {
            var hour = Math.floor(this.state.count/3600),
            minutes = Math.floor((this.state.count - hour*3600)/60),
            seconds = (this.state.count - hour*3600 -minutes*60 ),
            temp = new Date(); 
            temp.setHours(hour, minutes, seconds);
        }
        
        return(
            <div>
                {temp.getHours()}:{temp.getMinutes()}:{temp.getSeconds()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Timer;
```

I am 100% sure the problem arises due to my ComponentDidMount function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using conditional operator properly.

This is the format :
**Condition ? ReturnIfTrue : ReturnIfFalse**

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.myInterval = this.props.isRunning ? setInterval(() => 
                { this.tick()}, 1000) : null
        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the nooby mistake :) I'll accept your answer when the time countdown is up.

Comment: There is no need for apologies on SO. It is a forum for sharing knowledge. Please use the green tick to accept the answer if it works.

Comment: I will, but there is a countdown for yet another 4 minutes for some reason.